# zlag in plot in R

Tags: r, time-series

I'm trying to figure out the idea behind the following command in R

```
plot(y=hare, x=zlag(hare))
```

So far as I understand zlag is going to shift the data to the right by 1 time period. How do I interpret this plot?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the future, please provide an [MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) when posting, including the data source. That said, I figure this is the `hare` data from the `TSA` library, i.e.:

```r
library(TSA)

data(hare)
plot(y=hare, x=zlag(hare))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-11-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

This is a "lag plot", which tells you something about structure/randomness in the time series data. As described e.g. [here](https://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/eda/section3/lagplot.htm), non-randomness of the lag plot suggests non-randomness in the underlying data.